# How to catch the server response, even if 400 bad request error occured?

Tags: javascript, promise

Consider following code. It's just a simple http post request with `axios` library.

```
axios.post('http://localhost/users', this.state)
        .then(function(response) {
          if (response.status == 201) {
            browserHistory.push('/features');
          } 
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        })
```

If user enters a wrong data to an input, the response from server holds info, e.g.

- password has to be longer then...
- mail missing the `@` sign
- etc...

**but** unfortunately, I don't know how to get into that response if there's a `400 bad request` status. It just shows the error, but I'm unable to get the response.

If the response status is `201`, it properly shows the response. But in case of `400`, even if I change the condition and add `else if (response.status == 400) { console.log(response) }` it doesn't show up the response.

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: does the code fall through to the `.catch` perhaps?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just looking at the axios documentation, it looks like the response should be exposed in the error object (i.e. `console.log(error.response)`).

More information about different info provided when the response code falls out of 2xx here: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#handling-errors

Answer (score 9):

you need to log the data of the response:

```
axios.post('http://localhost/users', this.state)
        .then(function(response) {
          browserHistory.push('/features');
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error.response.data); // this is the part you need that catches 400 request
        });
```